# Understanding c# class markup like SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite

using SQLite library, I can create a class like

```
namespace MyApp
{
    [Table("mydatatable")]
    public class MyData
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Column("_id")]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Unique, NotNull]
        public Guid GUID { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(256), NotNull]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [NotNull]
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }

        public int MyNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then I can create a Database class like

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public class SQLiteDatabase
    {
        protected SQLiteConnection conn;

        public SQLiteDatabase()
        {
        }

        public void Attach(string dbName)
        {
            conn = new SQLiteConnection(dbName);
        }

        public void CreateTable<T>()
        {
            conn.CreateTable<T>();
        }

        public int Insert(Object T)
        {
            return conn.Insert(T);
        }
    }
}
```

This is all wonderful and makes using SQLite very easy.  But how could I write my own code to do something different?  For example, rather than write the data to SQLite database, let's say I wanted to convert the MyApp instance and send it over the nework.

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public class MyDatabaseHandler
    {
        public void CreateTable<T>()
        {
            // How do I get the table name "mydatatable"?
            // How do I get the column names and types?
            // Once I get that information, I can send a POST to my server and create a table on the backend
        }

        public int Insert(Object T)
        {
            // How do I get the table name "mydatatable"?
            // How do I get the column names and values of each data member?
            // Once I get that information, I can send a POST to my server and insert the record.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Look into Serialization in .Net

You can convert your classes down to XML files and then pass the XML file across the network and load them at the new location into your class.

Additionally you could look into using TCP but regardless you're going to have to convert your data to some type of serialized class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use reflection. Try this code:

```
public class MyDatabaseHandler
{
    public void CreateTable<T>()
    {
        // How do I get the table name "mydatatable"?
        var type = typeof(T);
        var tableAttribute = (TableAttribute)type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TableAttribute), inherit: false).FirstOrDefault();
        var tableName = tableAttribute?.Name;


        // How do I get the column names and types?
        var columns = type.GetProperties()
            .Select(p => new {type = p.PropertyType, name = p.Name })
            .ToArray();
    }

    public int Insert(Object T)
    {
        var type = T.GetType();
        // see previous method
    }
}
```